# PHP and XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I was **successfully** using the following code to merge multiple large XML files into a new (larger) XML file.  Found at least part of this on StackOverflow

> ```
>    $docList = new DOMDocument();
>
>     $root = $docList->createElement('documents');
>     $docList->appendChild($root);
>
>     $doc = new DOMDocument();
>
>     foreach(xmlFilenames as $xmlfilename) {
>
>         $doc->load($xmlfilename);
>
>         $xmlString = $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
>
>         $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
>         $query = self::getQuery();  // this is the name of the ROOT element
>
>         $nodelist = $xpath->evaluate($query, $doc->documentElement);
>
>         if( $nodelist->length > 0 ) {
>
>             $node = $docList->importNode($nodelist->item(0), true);
>
>             $xmldownload = $docList->createElement('document');
>
>             if (self::getShowFileName())
>                 $xmldownload->setAttribute("filename", $filename);
>
>             $xmldownload->appendChild($node);
>
>             $root->appendChild($xmldownload);
>         }
>
>     }
>
> $newXMLFile = self::getNewXMLFile();
> $docList->save($newXMLFile);
> ```

I started running into *OUT OF MEMORY* issues when the number of files grew as did the size of them.

I found an article [here](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/creating-large-xml-files-with-php/) which explained the issue and recommended using XMLWriter

So, now trying to use PHP XMLWriter to merge multiple large XML files together into a new (larger) XML file. Later, I will execute xpath against the new file.

Code:

> ```
> $xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
> $xmlWriter->openMemory();
> $xmlWriter->openUri('mynewFile.xml');
> $xmlWriter->setIndent(true);
> $xmlWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
>
> $xmlWriter->startElement('documents');
>
> $doc = new DOMDocument();
>
> foreach($xmlfilenames as $xmlfilename) 
> {
>     $fileContents = file_get_contents($xmlfilename);
>     $xmlWriter->writeElement('document',$fileContents);
> }
>
> $xmlWriter->endElement();
> $xmlWriter->endDocument();
> $xmlWriter->flush();
> ```

Well, the resultant (new) xml file is **no longer correct** since elements are escaped - i.e.

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

```
&lt;CONFIRMOWNX&gt;
&lt;Confirm&gt;
&lt;LglVeh id=&quot;GLE&quot;&gt;
&lt;AddrLine1&gt;GLEACHER &amp;amp; COMPANY&lt;/AddrLine1&gt;
&lt;AddrLine2&gt;DESCAP DIVISION&lt;/AddrLine2&gt;
```

Can anyone explain how to take the content from the XML file and write them properly to new file?

I'm burnt on this and I KNOW it'll be something simple I'm missing.

Thanks.
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, the problem is that [**XMLWriter::writeElement**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-element.php) is intended to, well, write a complete XML element. That's why it automatically sanitize (replace `&` with `&amp;`, for example) the contents of what's been passed to it as the second param.

One possible solution is to use [**XMLWriter::writeRaw**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-raw.php) method instead, as it writes the contents as is - without any sanitizing. Obviously it doesn't validate its inputs, but in your case it does not seem to be a problem (as you're working with already checked source).

Comment: XMLWriter::writeRaw did the trick for me.  Tried it once but used it incorrectly since it only takes one parameter - i.e. XMLWriter::writeRaw (string $content).  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, Not sure why it's converting it to HTML Characters, but you can decode it like so

htmlspecialchars_decode($data);

It converts special HTML entities back to characters.

Comment: tried  $xmlWriter->writeElement('document', htmlspecialchars_decode($fileContents)); -- no luck